# File not found exception with Docker

Tags: docker, image, dockerfile, containers

I have created a dockerfile where I plan on writing a CSV file in my application to a data folder like /data/csvFileName.csv.

In my dockerfile I have the command

`RUN mkdir data/`

So that I can create a folder named data on my docker image and that my application has a place to write to. However when I try to read it with a FileInputStream such like

`FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("data/csvFileName.csv");`

I get an error that the file is not found. Is this an issue with the way I am declaring the path in the FileInputStream?

Thanks

Comment: Since `data/` is a relative path, it's important what it's relative to. They might point to the same place and they might not. We can't really see that from your question.

Comment: I call RUN mkdir data/ att the beginning of my Dockerfile before any files or copys have taken place. Is there a way I can check the path of it?

Comment: To debug further, you can _e.g._ `docker run --rm your-image ls -ld /data` to run a new container with an arbitrary command (overriding the Dockerfile `CMD`) based on your built image.  Are you actually copying the file into your image too (in which case `COPY` will create the directory for you)?

Comment: I get this drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Feb 14 11:34 /data when running the command. I have code in my java application to write to data/csvFileName.csv but I don't have a COPY command in my Dockerfile to copy the CSV file because I only create the CSV file when the application is running so how could I copy it as the image and Dockerfile commands need to be run before the application starts correct?